# How to iterate this array to match all possible connections

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

As a person that couldn't grasp recursion, I'm getting an array that has unlimited depth on parent <> child id links. This is a category list from an ecommerce platform (Shopee). And I'm trying to build a relationship list between all the categories and subcategories from the array below.

```
How to get this 

Women's Clothing -> Tshirt -> Trending
                           -> Promotion

Shoes -> Hiking Shoe -> Winter Shoe

From the array below

$category = Array(
  [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 16
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [category_name] => Women's Clothing
                    [has_children] => 1
                 )
  [1] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 18
                    [parent_id] => 16
                    [category_name] => Tshirt
                    [has_children] => 1
                 )
  [2] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 901
                    [parent_id] => 18
                    [category_name] => Trending
                    [has_children] => 0
                 )
  [3] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 23
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [category_name] => Shoes
                    [has_children] => 1
                 )
  [4] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 100
                    [parent_id] => 23
                    [category_name] => Hiking Shoe
                    [has_children] => 1
                 )
  [5] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 120
                    [parent_id] => 100
                    [category_name] => Winter Shoe
                    [has_children] => 0
                 )
  [6] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 1400
                    [parent_id] => 18
                    [category_name] => Promotion
                    [has_children] => 0
                 )
)
```

Comment: `Clothing -> Tshirt -> Sportswear` This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: This is just a hypothetical category I added, sorry for the confusion. Let me rephrase the terms

Comment: Ok so you are trying to build a list. What kind of problem are you facing? Where's the code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search should do for a start. No need to apply recursion here (though you can)

Comment: You should tag your question with the programming language that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You could first group the items by their parent key, and then perform a depth-first traversal through the data:

```php
function dfs(&$childrenfor, $id, $path) {
    if (isset($childrenfor[$id])) {
        foreach($childrenfor[$id] as $item) {
            yield from dfs($childrenfor, $item["category_id"], [...$path, $item["category_name"]]);
        }
    } else {
        yield $path;
    }
}

// first group the items by parent key
foreach ($category as $item) {
    $childrenfor[$item["parent_id"]][] = $item; 
}
// ...then use depth-first traversal to collect the root-to-leaf paths in the tree
$result = [...dfs($childrenfor, 0, [])];
```

The `$result` would have the following for your example data:

```php
[
    ["Women's Clothing", "Tshirt", "Trending"],
    ["Women's Clothing", "Tshirt", "Promotion"],
    ["Shoes", "Hiking Shoe", "Winter Shoe"]
]
```

I guess you can take it from there to generate a format that suits you.